# RxJava map and emit as soon as a single map completed

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to map/convert an object to another object in background thread and have it on main thread as soon as a single conversation is completed.

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5)
            .map(new Func1<Integer, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Integer integer) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mapping number " + integer);
                    return String.valueOf(integer) + " mapped on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String integer) {
                    Log.d(TAG, integer + " received on: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });
```

The Result is:

```
D: mapping number 1
D: mapping number 2
D: mapping number 3
D: mapping number 4
D: mapping number 5
D: 1 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: 2 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: 3 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: 4 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: 5 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: onCompleted on: main
```

However the conversion may took a while and I expect to receive them as soon as the conversion is done.

```
D: mapping number 1
D: 1 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: mapping number 2
D: 2 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: mapping number 3
D: 3 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: mapping number 4
D: 4 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: mapping number 5
D: 5 mapped on: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 received on: main
D: onCompleted on: main
```

Comment: What's your question? RxJava will do just like your description. The logs in your question is just because the conversion is too fast. Add `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the map function and you will see different logs.

Comment: @zsxwing yep that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to set the global buffer size, just use the `observeOn(Scheduler, int)` overload where you can specify the prefetch value to be 1. That will only ask for the next value if the previous value has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to RxJava applying backpressure on the operators in the chain you are using above. The downstream operators such as ObserveOn request data from upstream by chunks, and not by individual items for efficiency. If you set the buffer size to one, this will effectively achieve of what you would expect with cost of efficiency:

```
-Drx.ring-buffer.size=1
```

Specifically that would be quite awful for upstreams that have expensive roundtrip calls.

**EDIT**:

You can use zip with BehaviorSubject to sort of serialize your down and up stream emissions:

```
BehaviorSubject<Void> signal = BehaviorSubject.create();
signal.onNext(null); // <- pair up the signal with the first item immediately
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5)
        .zipWith(signal, (item,v)->item) //only emit a next item when there is a "receipt acknowledgement" from the down stream
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //<- needed to avoid fetching subsequent items in UI thread
        .map(new Func1<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Integer integer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mapping number " + integer);
                return String.valueOf(integer) + " mapped on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String integer) {
                Log.d(TAG, integer + " received on: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                signal.onNext(null);  //<- acknowledge receipt - allow emitting next item from upstream
            }
        });
```